# Include handsontable in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, handsontable

I would like to add a handsontable to a plugin which I#m currently trying to develop for WordPress.
The table shall be visible in the Admin dashboard.

I could not manage to display the table at all.

Is there a general obstacle running handsontable in Wordpress?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you bound your .js file with the proper method ( wp_register_script and wp_enqueue_script )?.

You should do it like this:

```
// Registering the back-end scripts
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_backend_content_scripts' ); 


// ! Calling the back-end scripts 

function my_backend_content_scripts(  ) {

        if( is_admin() ){ 
            // parameter ( name, script_url, depencys, version, include in header )
            wp_register_script( 'my_js', 'www.fullscript_url.com/handsontable.js', array('jquery'), null, true );  
            wp_enqueue_script( 'my_js');                

        }       

}
```